# Swig typemap internal constructor to protected

Tags: c#, c++, swig

My C# code is using a third-party library, written in C++ and using Swig to wrap it in C# (*three projects here, MyCodeCS, ThirdCpp and ThirdCs*)

So if I have class Acpp with public constructors `Acpp()` and `Acpp(int)` in cpp, I end up in the wrapped C# version with class Acs, properly defined constructors `Acs()` and `Acs(int)` (so far, so good), both of them using an internal, swig-generated, constructor: `Acs(IntPtr cPtr,bool)`.

*(Of course both the cpp and the cs classes are named A, but for clarity I'll named them with the cpp and cs suffixes)*

Now, I am integrating a new cpp module (MyCodeCpp), which contains a class Bcpp, which inherits from Acpp. So far, so good: Bcpp inherits from Acpp, and I can call it from my C# code with no problem, using its `IntPtr`.

**My issue** is that for the only purpose of having my Bcs objects recognized as being a Acs, I need to define such Bcs class. Which is a pretty dumb one since I already got the cptr:

```
public class Bcs : Acs
{
    public Bcs(IntPtr cptr): base(cptr,true){}
}
```

The thing is... `Acs(IntPtr,bool)` is internal, which means that if I want to do that I need to either:

- add Bcs into thirdCS project and rebuild thirdCS, which is what I do right now and which works fine but displeases my chief architect because now we have a class which is supposed to belong to MyCodeCS as is a wrapper to a class of MyCodeCpp, which actually belongs to thirdCs
- **somehow modify the swig behavior so that `Acs(IntPtr,bool)` is protected internal instead of internal**, so it can be called by a MyCodeCS-based Bcs class

The thing is: I have no clue how to do that or even if it is possible ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show sample .i files?

Comment: Although I'm fairly sure your question has a simple solution it's really hard to understand the underlying problem through words alone. Can you show a *minimal* complete example, everything I'd need to try it out on my on dev environment? I can't even convince myself you're actually trying to solve the right right problem currently either.

Answer (score 1):

solved it.
simply needed to put

```
SWIG_CSBODY_PROXY(public, public, SWIGTYPE)
SWIG_CSBODY_TYPEWRAPPER(public, public, public, SWIGTYPE)
```

in my .i file